# Push-button and Jk flip flop

Tags: digital-logic

I have a mechatronics project where I have to use a push button switch at the input of A jk-flip flop my problem is when I click the switch it gives me the input 1 to the jk input the moment I remove my finger from the button it gets to zero. I want a way so that when I click the push button the input to be saved as 1 at the input of jk. I mean even when I remove my finger the input to remain 1 and get back to zero just when I click the switch again.

Comment: what you want when you press the push button for the second time? please provide more details of your requirement.

Comment: You have a mechatronics project and you use a JK-FF? Get a microcontroller, unless of course this is for an exhibit on retro-computing.

Answer (score 1):

I made this small circuit plan for you:
[image]

It basically splits the signal from the button and compares it with the JKs output to determin whether J or K shall be activated. Please notice that the purpose of the two inverters in the very middle is just adding a delay. You can achieve that in a more elegant way probably in reality (e.g. loading a capacitor to the threshold voltage).

Short summary:

if Button:

if J==1:

```
  K=1
```

if K==1:

```
  J=1
```

I hope that this answer was helpful!

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can be satisfied by this circuit. But doubt you forgot to mention your entire requirement.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYdwJZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>